# Get `this` from outside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How, or is it even possible, to get the `this` value from a function? I've made this snippet which saves `defaultValue` on the function, but I would like to read this from outside the function, directly on the `dom` element. Is that possible??

**I've made this, in jQuery:**

```
$("input").val(function() {
    var $label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']");
    this.defaultValue = $label.text();
    $label.hide()
    return this.defaultValue
}).click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == this.defaultValue) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
}).bind("blur", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val(this.defaultValue);
    }
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUZ3L/g6dMA/

Comment: You should use `.focus()` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: Which `this` do you want to access where? Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean by *"reading `this` directly on the DOM element"*? `this` is not a property of the function, it's a property of the execution context, i.e. the value of `this` is determined by how and when the function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it to the element represented in the DOM with jQuery's .data() function:

Do this on pageLoad:

```
$(this).data('defaultValue', $(this).val());
```

You can retrieve it later with:

```
alert($('#myElement').data('defaultValue');
```

...which will return the value set at pageload, rather than the current value of the input.

Comment: This is my approach, however, I have to get the data by getting $('#myElement').data().defaultValue; ... not your suggestion. But yes, I will use Data for this approach.

Comment: @KennethB: `$('#myElement').data().defaultValue` is equivalent to `$('#myElement').data('defaultValue')` and actually way cheaper (or it least it was). See http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2

Comment: What section are you referring to? I can't seem to figure out what you mean. And do you mean my appoach or yours, is way cheaper? :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function `$("input").val(function() {`, `this` refers to one element from the `$("input")` query.
Note that `$("input")` will return a list of elements, even if only one exists. Use `.get()` to select an element.
You can access `defaultValue` from `$("input").get(0).defaultValue`. (assuming you only want one element)

Comment: No, `this` refers the DOM Element. `document.getElementById('search').defaultValue` contains the label's text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue;" name="search" value="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are callback functions. Which means they are run when the event is fired, (from jQuery). So, `this` in this context is actually up to jQuery to decide.. in which case is the element to which the event is bound.

On a side note, it looks like you are looking for the placeholder attribute (available only in HTML5, but you can find plugins for older browsers)